# Force Firmware Upgrade Ubuntu-Mate

Tags: firmware

I believe my graphics card firmware may be infected by malware.  Is it possible to force update the firmware using Ubuntu-Mate in particular (or any other OS/Software)?

Comment: Why do you think so? ([XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378))

Comment: Many indicators but the one that has me most convinced was when I removed the hard drive and booted the PC, ran a hardware diagnostics and saw video card errors as well as misinformation listed under the specs of the video card hardware, such as "manufacturer: UEFI".  I also have not been able to remove the malware/problem even by low-level formatting the storage drive.

Comment: What kind of video card errors? Did you notice any malware-like activity?

Comment: The error directly related to the video card was detected by the integrated diagnostics tool provided by Dell.  I don't remember the exact code but am sure I can  get it again if need be.  I have had lots of malware activity ranging from adware to rootkits both in Windows and Linux , but again, it is not removable by storage device or anything else I've tried including BIOS updates.

Comment: Essentially, the infected firmware opens the door for everything else to come in and that is what I need to rectify but I'm not even sure that it is possible, which is why I asked the question.  One thing to note, the video card affected is both the on-board and a NVidia Quadro P1000, but the error is related directly to the on-board video adapter.  I don't have any options to update the firmware of either (unless the on-board adapter is updated with a bios update), so any input is appreciated.

Comment: Reinstall the OS is the only good solution if the PC is compromised.

Comment: I have done that many times which is another reason I believe that it's firmware based and for other reasons in the video card but I don't want to get off track from the question that I asked about forcing a firmware update and end up in a discussion about malware I should be off topic from what I started the post with.

Comment: Honestly, graphics adapter firmware sounds like a very unlikely attack vector. It's hard and costly to develop and must be designed with specific hardware in mind. If someone was determined enough to spend so many resources to cater the attack specifically to you (it's too resource-inefficient for non-targeted malware) then you must be a very valuable target. That means you should consider the system permanently compromised, trying to restore it is too risky - you don't know what else is infected.

Comment: But then, if they were determined to create a very sophisticated and costly piece of malware targeted at you, it's very unlikely they would make such rookie mistakes like breaking core functionality of the video adapter and following up with obvious malware infections. You don't spend so much money and time just to waste someone's time, you want to stealthily get what you want and disappear. So that doesn't make sense. I think you're either: 1) mis-identifying malware, or 2) restoring it with backups, or 3) installing it with some software, or 4) running vulnerable software and getting hacked

Comment: But maybe I'm wrong and you're a high-profile target for an idiot attacker with access to very sophisticated tools. If that's the case, trash the machine and consider all your data compromised.

Comment: Done it. Every time I trash machine it keeps coming back no matter what I try.

Comment: Then see my previous comment. You're either: 1) mis-identifying malware, or 2) restoring it with backups, or 3) installing it with some software, or 4) running vulnerable software and getting hacked. Malware that infects firmware wouldn't run on different hardware, firmware is not portable. The good news is your firmware is not infected.

Comment: I am identifying malware with various anti-malware software, I don't restore anything backups because I don't keep backups any longer and don't have a good back up of anything anylonger.  I only have to reinstall the OS (Windows/Linux) and it is infected.  As an example, I've uploaded logs from a recent install of Ubuntu-Mate, which can be found at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UeWDKRk-gnEN2f6kgUbQA-LFEgO-q70_?usp=sharing if youre interested.